# Clustering session storage location

Tags: tomcat, cloudbees

Regarding [app clustering](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/AppClustering), do we have to create a separate session storage location? You mention several options on that page (MySQL, CLoudant, RDS, etc.), does that mean we have to setup one of these and have it interact with our cluster somehow? Or is that all this automatically setup through [session stores](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/AppSessionStores)? If it's setup, is it setup using CloudBees MySQL behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

If the built in cloudbees session clustering service is turned on - then it is automatically setup for you in the default container.

For things like MySQL, etc.. then it is up to you to use a session provider/framework that support it for session data.